# Combining Boxcryptor and encrypted cloud service

Tags: encryption, cloud-storage

I want to store highly critical documents on a cloud storage as an additional backup. I am using boxcryptor which encrypts files before these get synced to cloud. Boxcryptor encrypts files using AES-256 cipher.

I am using a cloud storage service which encrypts the data at the client before storing on the cloud. So data remains encrypted at rest also. This service also uses AES-256.

Does dual encryption weakens the security?

== Edited ==

Keys are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dual encryption increases security, makes usage less practical and introduces problems when you want to recover your files.

So if you have to use dual encryption (because cloud service encrypts again no matter what) it's fine. But if you have freedom to choose, it's more practical and less troublesome to use a more complex key instead of encrypting two times.